# Programatically building expressions without compiling them

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I am trying to build expressions from other expressions, using the result of one as arguments for another, but I want to avoid compiling them. Given I have the working code below code how can I remove the `.Compile().Invoke(` bits to keep it as an expression all the way through? I can see it is a probably mix of Expression.Lambda() and Expression.Invoke() but what is the exact syntax?

```
Expression<Func<IActivator, TResult>> expressionA = ....;    
Expression<Func<T, TResult, TOut>> expressionB = ....;

Expression<Func<IActivator,TOut>> invoke_B_With_A = (activator) =>
    expressionB.Compile().Invoke(
        activator.Create<T>(), 
        expressionA.Compile().Invoke(activator)
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way seems to work, but can you simplify it?

```
var activatorParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IActivator), "activator");
Expression<Func<IActivator, T>> builder = (activator) => activator.Create<T>();

var invoke_B_With_A = Expression.Lambda<Func<IActivator, TOut>>(
    Expression.Invoke(expressionB,
        Expression.Invoke(builder, activatorParam),
        Expression.Invoke(expressionA, activatorParam)
    ), activatorParam );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
var activator = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IActivator), "activator");
Expression<Func<IActivator,TOut>> invoke_B_With_A =
    (Expression<Func<IActivator,TOut>>) Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(expressionB,
    activator,
    Expression.Invoke(expressionA, activator)
), new [] { activator });
```

Comment: Very few query providers actually support `Invoke`. so this is almost assuredly going to fail, for the same reason the OP's code is failing.

Comment: Getting closer but expressionB needs to be passed an instance of T, this solution is missing the `activator.Create<T>()` bit

Comment: @Servy I don't think any query providers are involved here, OP just constructs expression to compile and invoke (I think). There are no query providers mentioned in question also.

Comment: @Evk *Something* is going to be interpreting the expression.  Far and away the most common usage would be to use in in a query provider.  Even if it's being interpreted by something else, if that something else can't interpret the OP's solution, it's rather unlikely to be able to interpret this.

Comment: For the time being I can live with this in-memory using `Invoke` although obviously if someone can see a solution with a rewrittten expression using a visitor, without invoke, that would be better.

Comment: @Servy I don't see your point. OP says "Given I have the working code below ...", so that something else _can_ interpret OP solution, nothing is failing. @alastairtree - just replace `activator` with `Expression.Call(activator, methodToCall, ...)`.

Comment: @Evk Then this is simply equivalent, and simply no better.  That would indicate that the OP isn't actually using the expression as an expression, and is just compiling it, in which case odds are they shouldn't be using expressions *at all*.

Comment: @Servy expressions are often used for runtime code generation, there is nothing wrong with that. You generate expression, compile it and use, without any interpretation.

Comment: @Evk If the OP just wanted to run this code as code they could just compile the lambdas as delegates at compile time, and they'd be far faster and more effective, than writing them as expressions and compiling them at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the enthusiasm folks. It is actually part of a bigger dynamic expression building process, that is later compiled and executed in memory but useful to have in expression format rather than compiled code.